How to output non-English character to cmd.exe with anonymous pipes?
I wrote this code, which sends a command (using std::string, here I don't care about Unicode) through a pipe to cmd.exe and with another pipe I get the output:
string command = " cd C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\ && dir \n";

std::wstring convert(const char* str, int size) {
    int wideCharLength = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, str, size, nullptr, 0);
    std::wstring wstr(wideCharLength, L'\0');
    MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, str, size, &wstr[0], wideCharLength);
    return wstr;
}

void cmd() {
    SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sa;
    sa.nLength = sizeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES);
    sa.lpSecurityDescriptor = NULL;
    sa.bInheritHandle = TRUE;

    HANDLE hCommandReadPipe, hCommandWritePipe;
    HANDLE hOutputReadPipe, hOutputWritePipe;

    CreatePipe(&hCommandReadPipe, &hCommandWritePipe, &sa, 0);
    CreatePipe(&hOutputReadPipe, &hOutputWritePipe, &sa, 0);

    STARTUPINFOA si;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
    ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(si));
    si.cb = sizeof(si);
    si.hStdInput = hCommandReadPipe;
    si.hStdError = hOutputWritePipe;
    si.hStdOutput = hOutputWritePipe;
    si.dwFlags |= STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;

    CHAR cmdPath[MAX_PATH];
    ExpandEnvironmentStringsA("%SystemRoot%\\System32\\cmd.exe", cmdPath, MAX_PATH);

    CreateProcessA(cmdPath, NULL, NULL, NULL, TRUE, CREATE_NO_WINDOW, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi);

    CloseHandle(hCommandReadPipe);
    CloseHandle(hOutputWritePipe);

   
    while (true) {
        DWORD bytesWritten;
        
            WriteFile(hCommandWritePipe, command.c_str(), command.length(), &bytesWritten, NULL);
            command.erase();

        string temp_buff(4096, '\0');
        DWORD bytesRead = 0;
        BOOL readResult = ReadFile(hOutputReadPipe, &temp_buff[0], temp_buff.size(), &bytesRead, NULL);

        if (readResult && bytesRead > 0) {
            temp_buff.resize(bytesRead);
            
            wstring wbuff = convert((char*)temp_buff.c_str(), bytesRead);
            wcout << wbuff;
         
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    cmd();
    return 0;
}

Now, when a directory contains non-English characters, some are output properly but others are output with '?'.
I also tried this to set cmd to UTF-8 and then convert it to wide:
string command = "chcp 65001 && cd C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\ && dir \n"; 

std::wstring convert(const char* str, int size) {
            int wideCharLength = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, str, size, nullptr, 0);
            std::wstring wstr(wideCharLength, L'\0');
            MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, str, size, &wstr[0], wideCharLength);
            return wstr;
        }

Any other question/answer I came across didn't help at all.

You don't need 2 pipes, 1 pipe will suffice. Also, you are not managing the inheritance of the pipe(s) correctly. But, why are you using cmd.exe for this task at all? You should use a FindFirstFileW()+FindNextFileW() loop instead. Don't run cmd.exe for commands that have APIs available.
